# Django Rest Framework search_fields viewset from genericforeignkey field model

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

All models (Customer, Provider, Contact, Employee) have the same name field to search, in the main or generic model (Comments) have generic foreign key. I need search the field in the main model. It's that posible?

Models:

```
   class Customer(TimeStampedModel):
       name = models.CharField()

   class Provider(TimeStampedModel):
       name = models.CharField()

   class Contact(TimeStampedModel):
       name = models.CharField()

   class Employee(TimeStampedModel):
       name = models.CharField()


   class Comment(TimeStampedModel):
       content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
       object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
       commentator = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

Viewset

```
class CommentsViewSet(BaseViewSet):
       queryset = Comments.objects.all()
       serializer_class = CommentsSerializer
       search_fields = ["commentator__name",]
```

Message error:

> django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Field 'commentator' does not generate an automatic reverse relation and therefore cannot be used for reverse querying. If it is a GenericForeignKey, consider adding a GenericRelation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a `GenericRelation` field to each of your models that are able to receive comments, for instance:

```
   class Customer(TimeStampedModel):
       name = models.CharField()
       comments = GenericRelation('Comment', related_query_name='customer')

   class Provider(TimeStampedModel):
       name = models.CharField()
       comments = GenericRelation('Comment', related_query_name='provider')

   class Contact(TimeStampedModel):
       name = models.CharField()
       comments = GenericRelation('Comment', related_query_name='contact')

   class Employee(TimeStampedModel):
       name = models.CharField()
       comments = GenericRelation('Comment', related_query_name='employee')
```

Then you define your `search_fields` property as the list of all the `related_query_name`s in this way:

```
        search_fields = ["customer__name", "provider__name", "contact__name", "employee__name"]
```

Please refer [to this part of the documentation to know more about `GenericRelation`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#reverse-generic-relations)

Comment: Just FYI - I posted my answer 3 minutes before this one, and they are the exact same solution.

Comment: Sorry about that mate. You must have posted while I was typing. I did not intend to steel your answer. We should probably unify the answers into one? Don't know if that's even possible. Maybe some moderator can do it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to [add a `GenericRelation`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#reverse-generic-relations) to each of your models.

```
class Customer(TimeStampedModel):
   name = models.CharField()
   comment = GenericRelation(Comment, related_query_name='customer')

class Provider(TimeStampedModel):
   name = models.CharField()
   comment = GenericRelation(Comment, related_query_name='provider')
...

search_fields = ["customer__name", "provider__name", "contact__name", "employee_name"]
```